# how to use boost::bind with std::thread (in Wt c++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, bind, wt

I'm using Wt C++ framework and need to connect a push button with a class function. The below code works fine but it's needed to run the function doors_open_all on a thread to allow usage of other actions at the same time.

```
Wt::WPushButton *open_doors_button = new Wt::WPushButton("open all");
container_box->addWidget(open_doors_button);
open_doors_button->clicked().connect(boost::bind(&Servicemode::doors_open_all, this));
```

Something along the lines is needed:

```
open_doors_button->clicked().connect(boost::threaded_bind(&Servicemode::doors_open_all, this));
```

Comment: Can't you just launch a new thread inside the function `Servicemode::doors_open_all()`?

Comment: Apparently not, it doesn't allow use of non-static member function in such a way.

Comment: Inside `Servicemode::doors_open_all()` you can launch a thread to do its work giving it a lambda function if need be. But you can, actually, run non-static member functions in a thread too.

Comment: imho `bind` is completely horrible and I would always prefer a lambda

Comment: Galik your idea of using a lambda inside the function worked indeed. You can post it as a proper answer if you want. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand question corrently you need to run `doors_open_all` function in a new thread.

`boost::thread` constructor is internaly using `boost::bind` You don't need to be explicit.

So `open_doors_button->clicked().connect(boost:: thread(&Servicemode::doors_open_all, this));` should do the job.

Version with `boost::thread` and `boost::bind`:
`open_doors_button->clicked().connect(boost::thread(boost::bind(&Servicemode::doors_open_all, this)));`

Edit:
You can also try using `std::async` for this purpouse too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but boost::thread (also with bind) gives an deleted function error: ' error: use of deleted function ‘boost::thread::thread(const boost::thread&) '

Answer (score 0):

What does `Servicemode::doors_open_all()` do?

If I assume that what is taking a long time is just all backend stuff, so no widgets are being created, deleted or modified, then you can spawn a thread inside `Servicemode::doors_open_all()` to do all of that backend stuff. When it's done you have two possibilities:

1. Use `WServer::post()`, passing it the session id of your `WApplication` and a function, to notify the application that it should update its UI, and do all of your creating, deleting and modifying of widgets in that callback.
2. Grab the update lock of the `WApplication`:

   ```
   // Assuming that app is a Wt::WApplication*
   Wt::WApplication::UpdateLock lock(app); // lock is released when it goes out of scope
   ```

   When you have the update lock, you can go ahead and modify the widget tree.

In any case, when doing this, you have to also do these two things:

1. Enable server push beforehand by calling `app->enableUpdates(true)`. When the thread is done you can again disable server push with `app->enableUpdates(false)`.
2. When you have modified the widget tree, notify Wt that it should push these changes to the client with `app->triggerUpdate()`.

If what takes a long time is UI-related, then there's not much you can do, since Wt assumes that you only modify a `WApplication` and its widgets from a single thread at a time, i.e. when you have the update lock. The update lock is always grabbed automatically when handling an event coming from the client, like `WPushButton::clicked()`.

Server push is demonstrated in the `serverpush` example. You can find that under `examples/feature/serverpush` in the Wt source tree.